# How does one setup outgoing mail for Bitnami Canvas-lms

Tags: canvas-lms

I installed the Bitnami version of Canvas-LMS into AWS ECS. I have configured `outgoing_mail.yml` according to these [instructions](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/canvaslms/configuration/configure-smtp/). But when I add a user, they never get the confirmation email.

Looking at the `delayed_job.log` I can see that the message gets added to some sort of internal queue, but I have no idea how that queue gets processed by Canvas.

To verify that mail could be sent from the server, I installed and configured mailx. I am able to send messages from the server using mailx.

Where do I look to see why Canvas is not sending the mail?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to determine what's wrong here
might be the incorrect param in `outgoing_mail.yml`
or maybe it's the firewall that block your canvas from sending email

you can install gem like mailcatcher to test if canvas really send the email out

configure it like this(by default, mailcatcher capture messages on localhost:1025 on localhost:1080, and have web ui on localhost:)
change the address and port to mailcatcher

```yaml
development:
  address: "localhost"
  port: "1025"
```

> mailcatcher is a simple SMTP server that catch the mail essage and show it in the web